# Removing from a queue based on a condition

Tags: c, queue, structure, conditional-statements

I have a program with a queue and i need to remove the values from the queue based on a condition. The condition is

> If the value which was removed previously from the queue is more than the value which is going to to removed, then the value should be removed from the queue,
>   if not  the value is put back in to the queue again (Circular implementation).

Here is what i have done so far:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<malloc.h>
    #define MAX 180

    struct cakes{
      int spongecake;
      int meringue;
      int chocalate;
      int red_velvet;
      struct newcake *next;
    };

    struct Queue{
       int front;
       int rear;
       int count;
       int cake[10];
    };

    void order_out(struct cakes *); 
    void init(struct Queue *);
    int isFull(struct Queue *);
    void insert(struct Queue *,int);
    int isEmpty(struct Queue *);
    int removes(struct Queue *);

   main()
   {
      struct cakes *head;
      head=(struct cakes*)malloc(sizeof(struct cakes));
      order_out(head);
   }

   void init(struct Queue *q)
   {
        q->front=0;
        q->rear=10-1;
        q->count=0;
   }

   int isFull(struct Queue *q)
   {
        if(q->count==10)
        {
         return 1;
        }
       else 
       {
             return 0;
       }
   }

  void insert(struct Queue *q,int x)
  {
      if(!isFull(q))
      {
         q->rear=(q->rear+1)%10;
         q->cake[q->rear]=x;
         q->count++;
      }
  }

    int isEmpty(struct Queue *q)
    {
        if(q->count==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int removes(struct Queue *q)
    {
        int caked=NULL;

        if(!isEmpty(q))
        {
            caked=q->cake[q->front];
            q->front=(q->front+1)%10;
            q->count--;
            return caked;
         }
    }

    void order_out(struct cakes *theorder)
    {
    struct Queue s;
        int i,k;    
        int p=0;
        theorder->spongecake=20;
        theorder->meringue=75;
        theorder->chocalate=40;
            theorder->red_velvet=30;
        k=theorder->chocalate;  
        init(&s);

          for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
            insert(&s,theorder->chocalate);
            insert(&s,theorder->spongecake);
        insert(&s,theorder->meringue);
        insert(&s,theorder->red_velvet);
       }

    while(!isEmpty(&s)) 
    {   
      if(k>removes(&s)) //here i check whether the the value am going to remove is less than the chocalate value
      {
        printf("%d",removes(&s));
        k=removes(&s); //i make k the value which was removed so it will be compared in the next time.
      }
      else
      {
        p=removes(&s);
        insert(&s,p);
      }
   } 
}
```

**I am unable to get the desired output, what seems to be the problem here ?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in a debugger, line by line. However, in the `order_out` while-loop, if `k` is larger than the value you remove you do two other removals, which looks suspect. Are you sure you want to remove three items in that case?

Comment: no i only want to remove one. Ill check with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while-loop, you call removes(&s) more than once when you just want to remove at most one element.

for your condition,the while-loop can be:

```
while(!isEmpty(&s)) 
{  
    int tmp=removes(&s);
    if(k>tmp) {
        printf("%d should be remove,and k is %d\n",tmp,k);
        k = tmp;
        printf("k changed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d insert again,and k is %d\n",tmp,k);
        insert(&s,tmp);
    }
}
```

unfortunately, because of your condition and your data, it's a endless loop.

In your initial queue,

40 20 75 30 40 20 75 30 40 20 75 30

k=40, first 40 insert again.

to 20, 20 is removed, and k=20 now.

And the rest is not less than 20, they will be check and insert again over and over.

Addtionally, your remove() should return a value as error even when the queue is empty, for you dealing with this situation where you call remove().

Comment: any idea on how to make the value 20 change , so that other values will be printed ?

Comment: change your condition or data:1.condition can be:"If the value which was checked(not always removed) previously from the queue is not less  than (not more than) the value which is going to to removed, then the value should be removed from the queue, if not the value is put back in to the queue again"2. or the data: k = 40,data in queue is 30 20 15 10 ...

Answer (score 0):

Just **take a variable** and set its value to zero initially.

And in pop function before removing, just check if

> **value < variable**

.
If true, then POP else return.

Comment: well this is a queue not a stack and also i used a variable as you have mentioned but still am unable to get the desired output.