# Keeping track of each element getting inserted in to a queue

Tags: c, timer, queue, stack

I have a list of values which gets inserted in to a queue based on a condition and then again pushed in to a stack based on a condition. I want to keep a track of each variable getting inserted in to the queue and also store what time each element gets pushed in to the stack.
Simply  meaning i need to keep a timer. How can i do this? Currently i have no clue of keeping track of each element.

Here is the function of the program which requires the count:

```
while(!isqueueFull(&belt))
{
    insert(&belt,theorder->meringue);   //i want to keep a timer for each of these values getting inserted
    insert(&belt,theorder->chocalate);
    insert(&belt,theorder->red_velvet); 
    insert(&belt,(theorder->spongecake));       
}

value1=removes(&belt);
push(&baking,value1);

if(!isFull(&baking))
{
    for(;v<=MAX;v++)
    {
        if(counter%4==0)
        {
            value1=theorder->meringue;
            counter=counter+2;
        }
        else
        {   
                if(!isEmpty(&baking))
                  {
                     printf("\n%d",pop(&baking));
                  } 
                else
                {   
                    value2=removes(&belt);   

                    if(value1>=value2)    
                    {
                         while(!isFull(&baking))     
                         {      
                            push(&baking,value2); //if this gets executed i need to store the time where the value got in to stack.
                            value1=value2;
                            counter++;
                            break;           
                         }     
                     }

                    if(value1<value2 && value1!=value2) 
                    {   
                      while(!isqueueEmpty(&belt))
                      { 
                       insert(&belt,value2);    
                           break;        
                      } 
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some IDE(visual studio,etc) and debugging tools(as gdb) support to track variables when you are debugging,but you can track them in your program itself.

One way is  wirting two function to print all elements in the queue and stack.

Every time when you call insert()/remove()/push()/pop(),call the corresponding one in succession.

As the queue in  [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785272/removing-from-a-queue-based-on-a-condition), the function to show all elements in a queue may be:

```
int queue_display(struct Queue *q) {
    if(isEmpty(q)) 
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int p=q->front,count=q->count;
        printf("queue from front to rear:\n");
        do {
            printf("%d ",q->cake[p]);
            count--;
            p = (p+1)%10;
        } while(count>0);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

the one for stack is alike.